# To display menu on mouseover of an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div tag as menu and an image ,if i keep mouse cursor on image i have to see the menu and on mouse out the menu should not disappear.Is there any way to do this using jquery?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("img.image-selector").click(function () {
            alert($(this).attr("entity_id"));
        });
    });
</script>


<body>
   <form id="form1" runat="server" class="style1">
   <div id='one' style="color: #FFFFFF; display:none; background-color: #92DF7B;">
       <ul>
           <li>General</li>
           <li>Policy</li>
           <li>Manuals</li>
           <li>HEXA Documents</li>
           <li>ISO</li>
       </ul>
   </div>
```

I am confused what to proceed after this.

Comment: please make a working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: There is a good example of using mouseenter and mouse leave in the jquery docs: http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/

Comment: Please avoid using inline styles… [Why Use CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_Started/Why_use_CSS)

Comment: K Dave thanks ,Let me try to study that

Comment: Next time i will be carefull about it T J, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events on image like below, and call `show()` and `hide()` on menu `div`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("img.image-selector").mouseenter(function () {
            $('#one').show();
        });

        $("img.image-selector").mouseleave(function () {
            $('#one').hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is the [link](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for JQuery selectors

Comment: But can i know what code i should use for showing menu?

Comment: One more doubt, what if i have more than one image and its related menu. I want only one menu to be displayed at a time on mouse over. So will it work.Suppose second menu id is 'two' what shall i do?

Comment: you can have look at JQuery selectors http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/... using it you can have show/ hide as many menus as you want. You can select using id, classess, tags etc

Answer (score 0):

**Html**

```
<img src="" id="menuimage"/>
        <ul class="hide">
           <li>General</li>
           <li>Policy</li>
           <li>Manuals</li>
           <li>HEXA Documents</li>
           <li>ISO</li>
       </ul>
```

**Css**

```
.menu{display:block}
.hide{display:none}
```

**Jquery**

```
<img src="" id="menuimage"/>
        <ul class="hide">
           <li>General</li>
           <li>Policy</li>
           <li>Manuals</li>
           <li>HEXA Documents</li>
           <li>ISO</li>
       </ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fLE2Y/